# php load list student

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, `students`:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Category | GroupName | StudentLastName | StudentFirstName |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

All entries in the `students` table relate by `GroupName`

My second table is `DailyStudentCheck`. It has the same fields, plus `Avalability`.

There are 20 students in every group in the table `DailyStudentCheck`.

I created something like:

- StudentLastName, StudentFirstName
- StudentLastName1, StudentFirstName1
- StudentLastName2, StudentFirstName2
- ... up to 20

AND I CAN'T LOAD THEM INTO FIELD, ONLY ONE BY ONE

How can I do this when I choose `GroupName` all Students belong to this group
fill it up automatically? I don't know if I have to create 20 times Names.

```
    Table Student
```

Category    Groupname   StudentLastName StudentFirstName
daycare          1d          test           test
                         test1          test1
                         test2          test2

daycare          2d          king           king
                         king1          king2
                         king3          king3

Kindergarten    1k           nrw            nrw 
                         nrw            nrw 
                         nrw            nrw

```
    Table Daily Check Student
```

I need insert all student from (table student) under group 1d in group 1d under (daily check student)
Category    Groupname   StudentLastName StudentFirstName    Avalability
daycare         1d                                          present/ubsent

Comment: post what you had tried so far, and also you did not specify what problem you exactly experiencing. You had also a table of repeating data. Use normalization.

Comment: i have no idea what you're asking..... even disregarding the text in _CAPS_, I still don't understand what you mean by "choose groupname".  are you talking about a query (select/insert/update?) or displaying html or..?

Comment: category(daycare,kindergarten) GroupName (1d,2d,3d belong to daycare) i need when i choose in category :daycare: and on groupname :1d: list of student what belong to groupname 1d automaticly insert lastname firstname and teacher just put check on avalability (presend ir upsent)

Comment: you're going to need to post some code or diagrams or queries you already have...  my previous comment still stands.  I don't even understand if you're trying to write a query or display this data or use a form to input it.